# PHP Hiding Last 3 Chars Every Word

Tags: php

**Example String:**

> AAAAAA BBBBB CCCCCCC

**Output:**

> AAAXXX BBXXX CCCCXXX

I need to hide every last 3 chars of words. I tried str_replace but I can't make it. Thanks for help

```
$replacement = "***"; 
if (stripos($name, ' ') !== false) { 
$star = substr($name, 0, -3).$replacement;
}
```

I tried this but code only hide last word's 3 char. I need every word. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please share that code?

Comment: @Luca I updated my question.

Comment: what should happen, when a word has less then 3 chars ? can there be 2 or more spaces as delemiter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split your string up, replace the last three characters, and then reassemble it.

```
$replacement = "***"; 

// break your string into an array based on the spaces
$temp = explode(' ', $name) ;

// our temporary name
$newName = '' ;
// loop through each part of the original name
foreach($temp as $section) {
    // append our modified string along with a space
    $newName .= substr($section, 0, -3).$replacement . ' ' ;
}

// set $name = $newName without the trailing space
$name = substr($newName,0,-1) ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
$replacement = "***"; 
$star = "";
$pieces = explode(" ", $name);
foreach ($pieces as $piece){
    $star .= substr($piece, 0, -3).$replacement." ";
}
```

Comment: This code is perfectly fine. Can't getting who down voted this answer? As this question itself is semi clear that it has not been mentioned that how many string characters or limit would be there, how many delemiters would be there. So, no one can give an EXACT answer. So, i think @alexandr's answer is fine. There is nothing to downvote it!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you,  @HetalChauhan! But I don't think about my reputation. Even if somobody downvote me without any reason, it wouldn't make my programming skills worse then they are=)

Comment: This answer is more than enough to solve the poster's issue. It should not have been voted down so I gave it a deserved up-vote.

Comment: The code might (or might not) be correct. But a good answer should also contain a description how it solves the problem. Code alone is rarely useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function,

```
function replaceLastThreeChars($string){
    $reversed_string = strrev($string);
    $replaced_string = str_replace(substr($reversed_string,0,3),"XXX",$reversed_string);
    return strrev($replaced_string);
}
```

If you have a sentence, then you can slice it using spaces and call to this function and finally recreate the sentence.

Comment: Thank you so much!